# str contains equivalent for datetime64 pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, contains

I have a bunch of data as follows and I only want the 2019 entries.

```
+----------+
|   Date   |
+----------+
| 20190329 |
| 20180331 |
| 20190331 |
| 20180331 |
| 20190401 |
+----------+
```

Date type is `datetime64[ns]`. I tried `df = df[df['Date'].str.contains('2019')]` before I'd checked the type and it gives `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: Looks like integers? Try converting to string first: `df[(df['Date'].astype(str).str[:4] == '2019')]`

Comment: You should be able to access the `.year` attribute directly. See the [datetime docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#time-date-components)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a column of integers. In this instance, my recommended solution would be a conversion to datetime, following which you'd access the year attribute:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str)).dt.year == 2019  # you compare ints

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Date, dtype: bool

df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str)).dt.year == 2019]

       Date
0  20190329
2  20190331
4  20190401
```

Another alternative (slightly faster, but I don't like this because of the potential for abuse) would be to slice the strings and compare:

```
df['Date'].astype(str).str[:4] == '2019'  # you compare strings

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's in `datetime64[ns]` format, you could do something as simple as:

```
df=df[df.Date.dt.year==2019]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check with `//`

```
(df.Date//10000).eq(2019)
Out[58]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```